# Error building g++ 4.8.1 on CentOS

Tags: centos6, failed-installation, g++4.8

Can anybody suggest what's going wrong with my attempted g++ 4.8.1 install on CentOS 6?

The installed compiler is g++ 4.4.7.

The make step ends shortly after this:

```
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/mxhome/charrison/gcc-4.8.1/gcc-4.8.1/build-gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
```

The config.log contains this seemingly-innocent remark concerning object file suffixes:

```
configure:4390: checking for suffix of object files
configure:4412: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
configure:4416: $? = 0
configure:4437: result: o
```

The word 'error' occurs in the config.log file here (and my g++4.4 would certainly fail the test):

```
configure:4936: checking whether g++ accepts -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
configure:4953: g++ -o conftest -g -O2   -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc conftest.cpp  >&5
g++: unrecognized option '-static-libstdc++'
conftest.cpp:11:2: error: #error -static-libstdc++ not implemented
configure:4953: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #if (__GNUC__ < 4) || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ < 5)
| #error -static-libstdc++ not implemented
| #endif
```

But I don't know if that's fatal or not.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably obsolete, but I ran into the same problem and could fix it by installing `libstdc`.